# ANDROID STUDIO, Something written in editText should stay there untill the user edits it again. it should stay there even if app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am trying to make an app in android studio. I want my app to store what user  types in the app in editText. Even if user opens the app after 1 week it should stay there in edit text. thanks.

Comment: Save the data to a file, and load it again from that file.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow
When the app goes to idle or background save the data written in edittext with preferences check the preference when app is opened and prefill the edittext. If you want coding help then let me know.  Hope this will give you and give you tha bacis

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to achieve this is by using `SharedPreferences`

To detect when the user edits the value of the `editText`, use `addTextChangedListener`, and immediately store it using `SharedPreferences` The code for this is as following,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListener<EditText>(editText) {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(EditText target, Editable s) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
            editor.putString("KEY", editText.getText().toString()).apply();
        }
    });
```

The above code will save the `editText` value. To retrieve the stored value when the user opens the app later, the following code shall be used,

```
SharedPreferences editTextPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editText.setText(editTextPref.getString("KEY"));
```